# Share PowerApps Apps & Connections With Groups

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, usergroups

We have a suite of apps we are developing. We have already rolled the app out to about 50 users and have over 200 more. Sharing connections (custom connection & connector) and the apps have become super cumbersome. Long story short, this is a lot of time. Each time we have a new user we have to share 3 apps, 2x connections, and setup access on an internal method we have. We are using SQL, not CDS.

This has been misery. Is there a way to create 1x address that I would share with the Apps/Connection and I would just add users to this group? Would save us time to just add users to the one list. Then access is just shared via this common group. Does anyone know a better method to deploy powerapps like this? We can't share to "everyone". Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Azure Active Directory Security Group you can give them access to the connector and powerapp. See: https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/sharing-powerapps-with-multiple-users/

There are some kind of distinctions between Security Groups, Distribution Groups, O365 groups, and on prem vs Azure. I couldn't tell you the difference between them all, but you can follow [Microsoft's instructions on how to share a canvas app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/share-app) which will go through some of these different methods of sharing.